# Microsoft Excel Conditional Formatting for Dates and Prices

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016, conditional-formatting, conditional-statements

I'm looking to conditionally format a table following this general idea; I have short dates in one column and years in the headers for several other columns, Id like to highlight the cell when the years converge. Attached is a snip from my spreadsheet inside the red circle is the first date and inside the yellow circle is the second date, finally the green circle would be the cell that gets highlighted because the years correspond to each other.

Snip of Spreadsheet
[image]

Manually done
[image: Manually done]

Comment: "...when the years converge." what, exactly, does that mean? Can you show us what the expected result would be as well as let us know what you have tried and how it fails to achieve the goal

Comment: I may have worded that phrase poorly, let me attach a snip of it done manually. I struggle with the creation of formulas myself but I tried to word a IF statement. I think it might have to be an IF AND statement

Comment: You do need an `IF` `AND` statement. [A quick online search](https://www.ecosia.org/search?method=index&q=excel%20if%20and%20formula) yields multiple results on how to do this

Comment: Just to confirm because I'm getting an error would it look as such?
=IF(AND(YEAR($G$3:$G$13)=YEAR($K$1:$R$1)))

Comment: Try `=IF(YEAR($G3:$G3)=YEAR(K$1:K$1))`

Comment: I keep receiving a syntax error with that formula. While I understand the logic behind the formula, it seems to have a problem with the = in the middle of the formula.

Comment: Just realized: In a condition you don`t need the if, `=YEAR($G3:$G3)=YEAR(K$1:K$1)`

Comment: Awesome, that did the trick, I just had to adjust it to the full amount of dates and change the cell format in the checked columns. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the first conditional entry is in cell `F3`, EOL Date is in `Col A` and the years are in `row 1`

Highlight the cells to be formatted. Use Conditional formatting>New Rule and use formula `=F$1=YEAR($A3)`  Then select your formatting.